# How do i navigate through a list of widget

Tags: flutter, dart

When i press a button in MyLibrary() i want goto MyHome() .How can i make that possible from below code

```
const List<Widget> widgetOptions = <Widget>[
  MyHome(),
  FavScreen(),
  SearchScreen(),
  MyLibrary(),
];


class Home_ScreenState extends State<Home_Screen> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  static final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _drawkey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  ScrollController listScrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          key: _drawkey,
          extendBody: true,

          
          // ------------BODY---------------
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: listScrollController,
            child: Container(
     
              child: widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
            ),
          ),
```

I wanted to navigate through a List of widgets in the  same Scaffold

Comment: use BottomNavigationBar

Comment: Alternatively use TabBar

Comment: TabBar is there but i want to go to a specific widget when i press a button in MyLibrary().

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback method on `MyLibrary`

```dart
class MyLibrary extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyLibrary({super.key, required this.navToHome});
```

And call this method on your button tap `widget.navToHome();`.

And your main widget

```dart
class _MainWidgetState extends State<MainWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late List<Widget> widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    // MyHome(),
    // FavScreen(),
    // SearchScreen(),
    MyLibrary(navToHome: () {
      controller.animateTo(0);
      setState(() {}); //might not be needed for controller
    }),
  ];
  late final TabController controller =
      TabController(length: widgetOptions.length, vsync: this);
```